# Promises and garbage collection

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, promise, react-redux, garbage-collection

I have setup a project with react-redux and I use redux-thunk in my action-creators to do fetching. Here is an example of my thunk:

```js
   export const doPostRequest = id => {
     return (dispatch, getState) => {
          const { id : initiailId } = getState().currentSelection
          return api.post(id).then(response => {
             if (!isEqual(initialId, getState().currentSelection.id)){
                return;
             }
             dispatch(someOtherAction(id))
             return Promise.resolve(true)
          })
          .catch(err => {})
      }
}
```

As you can see i want to escape the doPostRequest if the currentSelection of my state is changed by the time the response is receieved. Otherwise I return Promise.resolve(true) so the onSubmit in MyComponent can reset the form:

Inside a component (which is a form) i have the following for onSubmit:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent{

   onSubmit = id => {
       this.props.dispatch(doPostRequest(id))
          .then(shouldReset => shouldReset && resetForm())
   }

   render(){
       return <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>.....</form>
   }

}
```

In most cases, when I really dont have to do anything else except fetching values, I dont do a Promise-chain on the thunk, even though it returns a promise, but here I need to do a resetForm once the postrequest is a success.

Is this implementation good enough, also when it comes to GC ? How are Promises garbage collected ? Is there a problem if I return a fetch().then() without chaining it further?